# Need assistance with Regular Expressions in Qt (QRegExp) [bad repetition syntax?]

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

```
void MainWindow::whatever(){
    QRegExp rx ("<span(.*?)>");
    //QString line = ui->txtNet1->toHtml();
    QString line = "<span>Bar</span><span style='baz'>foo</span>";
    while(line.contains(rx)){
        qDebug()<<"Found rx!";
        line.remove (rx);
    }
}
```

I've tested the regular expression online using [this tool](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html). With the given regex string and a sample text of `<span style="foo">Bar</span>` the tool says that it the regular expression should be found in the string. In my Qt code, however, I'm never getting into my while loop.

I've really never used regex before, in Qt or any other language. Can someone provide some help? Thanks!

[edit]
So I just found that QRegExp has a function `errorString()` to use if the regex is invalid. I output this and see: "bad repetition syntax". Not really sure what this means.  Of course, googling for "bad repetition syntax" brings up... this post. Damn google, you fast.

Comment: Ahh. HTML & regex!! Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 immediately!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `QRegExp` only supports greedy quantifiers.  More precisely, [it supports *either* greedy *or* reluctant quantifiers, but not both](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qregexp.html#notes-for-perl-users).  Thus, `<span(.*?)>` is invalid, since there is no `*?` operator.  Instead, you can use

```
QRegExp rx("<span(.*)>");
rx.setMinimal(true);
```

This will give *every* `*`, `+`, and `?` in the `QRegExp` the behavior of `*?`, `+?`, and `??`, respectively, rather than their default behavior.  The difference, as you may or may not be aware, is that the minimal versions match as *few* characters as possible, rather than as *many*.

In this case, you can also write

```
QRegExp rx("<span([^>]*)>");
```

This is probably what I would do, since it has the same effect: match until you see a `>`.  Yours is more general, yes (if you have a multi-character ending token), but I think this is slightly nicer in the simple case.  Either will work, of course.

Also, [be very, very careful about parsing HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  You can't actually do it, and recognizing tags is—while (I believe) possible—much harder than just this.  (Comments, CDATA blocks, and processing instructions throw a wrench in the works.)  If you know the sort of data you're looking at, this can be an acceptable solution; even so, I'd look into an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Extra +1 for link to epic HTML regex answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response. I am in a very niche use and believe I know the HTML I'm dealing with.

Comment: @Airjoe: That counts as "be[ing] very, very careful" :)  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? If you want to remove the opening  tag and its elements, then the pattern

```
<span[^>]*>
```

is probably the simplest.

The syntax .*? means non-greedy match which is widely supported, but may be confusing the QT regex engine.